HTTP trace logging when using Spring Cloud Gateway in a SpringBoot fat JAR
We recently converted a Spring Boot application from a WAR running on Tomcat to a Spring Fat JAR. I would like the ability to record when an incoming HTTP request is recevied and when the response is sent out. I have attempted adding the following JVM property in both the startup script and programtically without seeing any results.
https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-gateway/reference/spring-cloud-gateway/reactor-netty-access-logs.html
As an added complexity we are using log4j2 for all logging within our application. I do not believe we are seeing any Netty logs at the moment despite attempts to set the Netty log level in application.properties and prgramitcally setting log4j2 as the Netty logger.
InternalLoggerFactory.setDefaultFactory(Log4J2LoggerFactory.INSTANCE);
Ideally we would like to be able to enable an access log with features simialr to those in Tomcat described here: https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/config/valve.html
I attempted enabling Netty logging be setting the following
-Dreactor.netty.http.server.accessLogEnabled=true
I was expecting to see access log similar to those procued by Tomcat. Instead I see nothing.
The build.gradle is as follows:
/*
 * This file was generated by the Gradle 'init' task.
 * 
 */

buildscript {
    ext.repos = {
        maven {
            url "${ARTIFACTORY_URL}/${PROXY_REPO_KEY}"
            credentials {
                username = "${ARTIFACTORY_USER}"
                password = "${ARTIFACTORY_PASSWORD}"
            }
        }
        mavenCentral()
    }
    repositories repos
}


plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'maven-publish'
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.7.16'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.0.15.RELEASE'

}

repositories repos


ext{
    if(project.hasProperty("RELEASE_NAME")){
        releaseName = project.getProperty("RELEASE_NAME")
        println "RELEASE_NAME is: "+releaseName
    }
    else{
        throw new GradleException("RELEASE_NAME not found neither from command line nor from gradle.properties")
    }

    set('springCloudVersion', "2021.0.8")
}

group = 'com.company.microservice'
version = releaseName
description = 'api-gateway'
java.sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
jar.enabled=false

configurations.runtimeOnly{
    if(project.hasProperty("os-build-deploy-profile")){
        exclude group:'org.glassfish.hk2.external', module:'aopalliance-repackaged'
        exclude group:'org.aspectj', module:'aspectjweaver'
        exclude group:'org.glassfish.hk2', module:'hk2-api'
        exclude group:'org.glassfish.hk2', module:'hk2-locator'
        exclude group:'org.glassfish.hk2', module:'hk2-utils'
        exclude group:'com.fasterxml.jackson.module', module:'jackson-module-jaxb-annotations'
        exclude group:'jakarta.activation', module:'jakarta.activation-api'
        exclude group:'org.glassfish.hk2.external', module:'jakarta.inject'
        exclude group:'jakarta.ws.rs', module:'jakarta.ws.rs-api'
        exclude group:'jakarta.xml.bind', module:'jakarta.xml.bind-api'
        exclude group:'org.javassist', module:'javassist'
        exclude group:'com.sun.jersey.contribs', module:'jersey-apache-client4'
        exclude group:'org.glassfish.jersey.core', module:'jersey-client'
        exclude group:'org.glassfish.jersey.core', module:'jersey-common'
        exclude group:'com.sun.jersey', module:'jersey-core'
        exclude group:'org.glassfish.jersey.ext', module:'jersey-entity-filtering'
        exclude group:'org.glassfish.jersey.inject', module:'jersey-hk2'
        exclude group:'org.glassfish.jersey.media', module:'jersey-media-json-jackson'
        exclude group:'javax.ws.rs', module:'jsr311-api'
        exclude group:'org.glassfish.hk2', module:'osgi-resource-locator'
        exclude group:'jakarta.annotation', module:'jakarta.annotation-api'
        exclude group:'javax.activation', module:'javax.activation-api'
        exclude group: "org.glassfish.jersey.core", module: "jersey-client"
        exclude group: 'com.google.code.findbugs', module:'annotations'
    }

    exclude group:'org.springframework.boot' , module: 'spring-boot-starter-logging'
    exclude group:'org.slf4j' , module: 'log4j-over-slf4j'
    exclude group:'org.apache.logging.log4j' , module: 'log4j-to-slf4j'
    exclude group:'org.apache.commons', module:'commons-collections4'
    exclude group:'org.apache.httpcomponents.client5', module:'httpclient5'
    exclude group:'org.apache.httpcomponents.core5', module:'httpcore5'
    exclude group:'org.apache.commons', module:'commons-pool2'
}


dependencies {
        compileOnly 'org.glassfish.hk2.external:aopalliance-repackaged:2.6.1'
        compileOnly 'org.aspectj:aspectjweaver:1.9.5'
        compileOnly 'org.glassfish.hk2:hk2-api:2.6.1'
        compileOnly 'org.glassfish.hk2:hk2-locator:2.6.1'
        compileOnly 'org.glassfish.hk2:hk2-utils:2.6.1'
        compileOnly 'com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-jaxb-annotations:2.9.9'
        compileOnly 'jakarta.activation:jakarta.activation-api:1.2.2'
        compileOnly 'org.glassfish.hk2.external:jakarta.inject:2.6.1'
        compileOnly 'jakarta.ws.rs:jakarta.ws.rs-api:2.1.6'
        compileOnly 'jakarta.xml.bind:jakarta.xml.bind-api:2.3.3'
        compileOnly 'org.javassist:javassist:3.22.0-CR2'
        compileOnly 'com.sun.jersey.contribs:jersey-apache-client4:1.19.1'
        compileOnly 'org.glassfish.jersey.core:jersey-client:2.35'
        compileOnly 'org.glassfish.jersey.core:jersey-common:2.35'
        compileOnly 'org.glassfish.jersey.ext:jersey-entity-filtering:2.35'
        compileOnly 'org.glassfish.jersey.inject:jersey-hk2:2.35'
        compileOnly 'org.glassfish.jersey.media:jersey-media-json-jackson:2.35'
        compileOnly 'javax.ws.rs:jsr311-api:1.1.1'
        compileOnly 'org.glassfish.hk2:osgi-resource-locator:1.0.3'
        compileOnly 'jakarta.annotation:jakarta.annotation-api:1.3.5'
        compileOnly 'javax.activation:javax.activation-api:1.2.0'       
        compileOnly 'com.google.code.findbugs:annotations:2.0.0'
        
    //implementation 'org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-gateway:3.1.8'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-webflux'
    implementation 'org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-gateway'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
    testImplementation 'io.projectreactor:reactor-test'
    
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test:2.7.15'
    
    implementation 'com.zaxxer:HikariCP:3.4.5'
    implementation 'org.json:json:20190722'
    implementation 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.14.1'
    implementation 'org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-core:2.17.1'
    implementation 'org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-api:2.17.1'
    implementation 'org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.9'
    implementation 'jakarta.ws.rs:jakarta.ws.rs-api:2.1.6'
    implementation 'org.springframework:spring-jdbc'
    
    implementation 'com.oracle:ojdbc8:21.1.0.0'

    compileOnly 'javax.servlet:javax.servlet-api:4.0.1'
    
}

dependencyManagement {
    imports {
        mavenBom "org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-dependencies:${springCloudVersion}"
    }
}

tasks.withType(JavaCompile) {
    options.encoding = 'UTF-8'
}

jar{
    manifest {
        attributes "Main-Class": "com.company.microservice.ApiGatewayApplication"
    }
    
    from {
        configurations.runtimeClasspath.collect { it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it) }
    }
    
    duplicatesStrategy(DuplicatesStrategy.EXCLUDE)
}

publishing {
    publications {
        maven(MavenPublication) {
            from components.java
            groupId = group
            artifactId = project.getName()
            version = version
            artifact ("${projectDir}/build/libs/"+project.getName()+"-"+version+".jar")
        }
    }
    repositories {
        maven {
            name 'nexus'
            url "${ARTIFACTORY_URL}/${REPO_KEY}"
            credentials {
                username "${ARTIFACTORY_USER}"
                password "${ARTIFACTORY_PASSWORD}"
            }
        }
    }
}


In order to route all log statements to the Log4j Core logging backend, you need to add bridges from all major logging APIs to Log4j API. The exact instructions will soon be available on the Log4j website (see staging website for a preview).
Reactor Netty uses a logging API wrapper (Loggers.Logger) that forwards all logs to SLF4J and is different from the one used by Netty (InternalLoggerFactory).
You need to install an SLF4J-to-Log4j API bridge: either log4j-slf4j-impl or log4j-slf4j2-impl depending on the SLF4J version.
Spring Boot makes it easier to keep track of logging bridges.
You just need to replace:
implementation 'org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-core:2.17.1'
implementation 'org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-api:2.17.1'

with:
// Only useful if you use Log4j API as logging API
implementation 'org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-api'
// Redirects `java.util.logging`, SLF4J and Log4j API to Log4j Core
runtimeOnly 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-log4j2'

Remark: The way you are assembling a fat JAR:
jar{
    manifest {
        attributes "Main-Class": "com.company.microservice.ApiGatewayApplication"
    }
    
    from {
        configurations.runtimeClasspath.collect { it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it) }
    }
    
    duplicatesStrategy(DuplicatesStrategy.EXCLUDE)
}

will cause you problems since it doesn't merge correctly resources with the same name coming from multiple JARs.
Consider using the Spring Boot bootJar task instead, since Spring Boot keeps dependencies in their original JAR packaging.
